# Using Netty 4 with Akka (Scala)

Tags: scala, netty, akka

I'm using scala to develop an application server. I'm using Netty 4 for my networking stuff and then I want to use Akka actor to process the message. Now I want to test the communication between different machines with remote actor. But I saw that akka remote actor is using Netty 3. So my question is can my application server run with both Netty 3 and 4 dependencies? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes... Netty 3 and Netty 4 can co-exist as those use different java packages.

Comment: I'm not at my laptop right now. I will test it and confirm later. :)

Comment: have you confirmed it ??

Comment: I can confirm that Netty 3 and 4 can co-exist on the same JVM.